# Xcode markup/documentation not working

Tags: swift, documentation, xcode8, markup, swift-extensions

I created an extension and added a description using `///`

```
extension Array where Element: UIView {

    /// Remove each view from its superview.
    func removeViewsFromSuperview(){
        self.forEach{ $0.removeFromSuperview() }
    }
}
```

However, when I use it the description does not show up:

[image]

But, descriptions for library functions show up:

[image]

So if anyone could tell me what I'm doing wrong in terms of the markup that would be great!

Comment: Have you saved the file with the array extension in it? Have you built the project? Have you quit Xcode and relaunched? These are all things that may help. Have you put the cursor in an instance of the method and checked the quick help? Is it listed there?